# sudo: allow one command to set one environment variable

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

On my Debian Stretch system, I have

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

in my `/etc/sudoers`.  I want to set up my system so that when running [sshuttle](http://sshuttle.readthedocs.io), I don't have to enter my password for the call

```
sudo PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages -- /usr/bin/python3 \
                                                  /usr/bin/sshuttle --method auto --firewall
```

So I created a file `/etc/sudoers.d/sshuttle` with the contents

```
username    ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/sshuttle --method auto --firewall
```

However, I get the error message

> sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables: PYTHONPATH

The optimal solution

1. should allow me to run exactly this one command with setting the `PYTHONPATH`, but would not affect the security of my *sudo* setup in, general, i.e., this restriction should still apply for the other entries in my `sudoers` files.
2. would not require me to change the *sshuttle* source code, i.e., it should work for the exact command specified above without modification.

**What I tried so far:**

1. modify the `/etc/sudoers.d/sshuttle` file to read `username ALL=NOPASSWD: PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/sshuttle --method auto --firewall`, but this seems not to be valid syntax

**Notes:**

1. I do not want to run the whole *sshuttle* command via sudo, as a) *sshuttle* doesn't need root rights except for the firewall part (the command this question about), and b) because then I always need to enter the passphrase for my SSH key (which is usually unlocked via *gpg-agent* for my own user, but not for the root user).

Comment: Did you try with `SETENV`? (see `sudoers` manual).

Comment: I'd love to write it up as an answer, but I have no way of testing it (no `sudo` on my OpenBSD machine, we use `doas`), so someone else has to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the PYTHONPATH you need is constant, you can use `/usr/bin/env` (most underrated unix tool ever...):

```
username    ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/env PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/sshuttle --method auto --firewall
```

Or write a short wrapper script that sets up the environment before `exec`ing the python script.

If the PYTHONPATH is *not* constant, you might just as well use `username ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`, since the user could override any python package that is used by sshuttle and put code doing anything imaginable in there.

Comment: Thanks, yes, `PYTHONPATH` is constant. However, for your suggestion, I'd need to modify the sshuttle source code (to put the `/usr/bin/env ...` there), and I'd prefer not to do this. I'll go with `SETENV`, as suggested by @Kusalanada in the comments.

Comment: As I said, in this case you are completely opening up your system, since the user can set PYTHONPATH to anything she likes, making sshuttle do anything she wants with full root permissions. With SETENV, you allow the user to control the environment for the privileged process, without any restrictions whatsoever.

Comment: Try it:
`mkdir /tmp/sshuttle; echo -e 'import os\nos.system("echo Gotcha; id")' > /tmp/sshuttle/cmdline.py; sudo PYTHONPATH=/tmp /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/sshuttle --method auto --firewall`

Comment: thanks, @aferber , for your concerns. you actually convinced me that this is the better solution. so I'll try to get a corresponding patch merged upstream into sshuttle, to allow for this setup.